# how to install & use numpy on macOS Ventura, ARM

Tags: python, macos, numpy

it's there, but computer says "no"...

```
% python --version
Python 3.11.3   

% find /opt -name "numpy"
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy

% export PYTHONPATH="/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy"

% echo $PYTHONPATH
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy

% python -c "import numpy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

Comment: what's the output of `which python`?

Comment: % ls -l $(which python)
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  25 May  3 09:28 /opt/local/bin/python -> /opt/local/bin/python3.11

Comment: You may have two different Python's installed, try doing `python -m pip install numpy` whereby doing so, this `python` refers to the current Python distribution you are using.

Comment: Thanks @Aeronautix, I get a “missing module” error message about pip. I’ll try to retread python from scratch - or install a Linux VM and get that to work.

Comment: Installing Python3 should also have installed pip. There's a builtin module to get pip if you don't have it: `python -m ensurepip`, this installs pip if it's not installed (does nothing if pip is already installed). See also: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

Comment: Thanks. I have something called pip3 installed. Maybe I just need to make a symlink to it?

Comment: I recommend working directly with the Python distribution you have, doing `python -m ensurepip` then `python -m pip install numpy`, whereby `python` is your Python distribution. I recommend using the syntax `python -m pip install PACKAGE` to install any future packages you may want.

Comment: And use `python -m pip ANY_PIP_COMMAND` for any pip command you want.